# Multiple time series plots for several stocks in R returns an error

Tags: r, ggplot2, quantmod

I have a time series data with multiple stocks. I would like to plot them in one plot in R.

I tried an existing answer in this website but I got an error. Here is my code:

```
library(quantmod)
library(TSclust)
library(ggplot2)
# download financial data

symbols = c('ASX', 'AZN', 'BP', 'AAPL')
start = as.Date("2014-01-01")
until = as.Date("2014-12-31")

stocks = lapply(symbols, function(symbol) {
    Close = getSymbols(symbol,src='yahoo', from = start, to = until, auto.assign = FALSE)[, 6]
   names(adjust) = symbol
    adjust
  })
```

### I tried the following from an exiting answer (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7820789/r-ggplot2-plot-several-time-series-in-a-plot))

```
qplot(symbols, value, data = as.data.frame(stocks), geom = "line", group = variable) +
  facet_grid(variable ~ ., scale = "free_y")
```

I got the following error:

Error: At least one layer must contain all faceting variables: `variable`.

- Plot is missing `variable`
- Layer 1 is missing `variable`

I would like to have similar to the following plot:

[image: here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error messages in the original code are caused by the fact that there is no column called `variable` in the data that is passed to `qplot()`. Additionally, in order to produce the desired chart, we need to extract the dates from the `xts` objects generated by `quantmod` so we can use them as the x axis variable in the chart.

With some adjustments to place the appropriate variables from the stock data into the `qplot()` specification we can produce the required chart.

We modify the code to read the list of stocks as follows:

- Convert the `xts` objects to objects of type `data.frame`
- Rename columns to eliminate ticker symbols so we can `rbind()` into a single data frame in a subsequent step
- Extract the `rownames()` into a data frame column

Having made these changes, the `stocks` object contains a list of data frames, one per stock ticker.

```
symbols = c('ASX', 'AZN', 'BP', 'AAPL')
start = as.Date("2014-01-01")
until = as.Date("2014-12-31")

stocks = lapply(symbols, function(symbol) {
     aStock = as.data.frame(getSymbols(symbol,src='yahoo', from = start, to = until, 
                         auto.assign = FALSE))
     colnames(aStock) <- c("Open","High","Low","Close","Volume","Adjusted")
     aStock$Symbol <- symbol
     aStock$Date <- rownames(aStock)
     aStock
})
```

Next, we use `do.call()` with `rbind() to combine the data into a single data frame that we'll use with` qplot()`.

```
stocksDf <- do.call(rbind,stocks)
```

Finally, we use `qplot()` with `Date` and `Close` as the x and y variables, and `facet_grid()` with `Symbol` to generate the facets.

```
qplot(Date, Close, data = stocksDf, geom = "line", group = Symbol) +
     facet_grid(Symbol ~ ., scale = "free_y")
```

...and the initial output:

[image]

Having generated the chart, we'll make some adjustments to clean up the x axis labels. On the default chart they are unintelligible because there are 251 different character values, and we need to rescale the axis to print fewer labels.

First, we convert the character-based dates with `as.Date()`. Second, we use the `ggeasy` package to adjust the content on the x axis.

```
stocks = lapply(symbols, function(symbol) {
     aStock = as.data.frame(getSymbols(symbol,src='yahoo', from = start, to = until, 
                         auto.assign = FALSE))
     colnames(aStock) <- c("Open","High","Low","Close","Volume","Adjusted")
     aStock$Symbol <- symbol
     aStock$Date <- as.Date(rownames(aStock),"%Y-%m-%d")
     aStock
})
stocksDf <- do.call(rbind,stocks)
library(ggeasy)
qplot(Date, Close, data = stocksDf, geom = "line", group = Symbol) +
     facet_grid(Symbol ~ ., scale = "free_y") +
     scale_x_date(date_breaks = "14 days") +
     easy_rotate_x_labels(angle = 45, side = "right")
```

...and the revised output:

[image]

**NOTE:** to chart the Adjusted Closing price, simply change the y variable in the `qplot()` function to `Adjusted`.

Comment: @Maryam - you're welcome. `ggplot2` is very powerful, but it's also very complex. Hopefully the explanation is clear enough so you can modify the code if you need to do so.

Answer (score 3):

While [Len Greski's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63559744/271616) has a great explanation and solution, I thought I'd provide an answer with a more 'standard' approach. Maybe some users will find it simpler.

```r
library(quantmod)
library(ggplot2)

symbols <- c("ASX", "AZN", "BP", "AAPL")
start <- as.Date("2014-01-01")
until <- as.Date("2014-12-31")

# import data into an environment
e <- new.env()
getSymbols(symbols, src = "yahoo", from = start, to = until, env = e)

# extract the adjusted close and merge into one xts object
stocks <- do.call(merge, lapply(e, Ad))

# Remove the ".Adjusted" suffix from each symbol column name
colnames(stocks) <- gsub(".Adjusted", "", colnames(stocks), fixed = TRUE)

# convert the xts object to a long data frame
stocks_df <- fortify(stocks, melt = TRUE)

# plot the data
qplot(Index, Value, data = stocks_df, geom = "line", group = Series) +
     facet_grid(Series ~ ., scale = "free_y")
```

[image]

Comment: Hello Joshua. Thanks for posting this answer. I recorded my observations in a [blog post](https://lgreski.github.io/dsdepot/2020/09/05/plotting-multiple-timeseries.html), since they're too long for a comment.

Comment: Thanks Len, appreciate you sharing your perspective!